# Is it common to write $f'^{2}(x)$, particularly when $f$ is a trigonometric function?

Tags: functions, derivatives, trigonometry, notation, exponentiation

It has been said many times that the notation for exponentiated or inverted trig functions, e.g.:

$$\sin^2(x), \tan^{-1}(x), \csc^3(x)$$

is confusing, ugly, and terrible in general, but nevertheless standard. So is it more common to write:
$$f'^2(x)\text{ or }f'(x)^2$$
To differentiate and then square a function $f$?

Comment: I prefer $f'(x)^2$.

Comment: $\tan^{-1} (x)$ does not mean the same thing as $\tan(x)^{-1}$

Comment: @Sandejo Edited.

Comment: I prefer $$\left( f'(x) \right)^2$$

Comment: People also sometimes write $f^{(n)}$ for the $n$th derivative of $f$. You could no doubt abuse this to make some really confusing expressions. $\cos^{2(2)}(x) = -2\cos(2x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you use superscripts to mean two different things. In $\sin^2$ and $\csc^3$, the superscripts refer to iterated multiplication (powers), whereas in $\tan^{-1}$, the superscript refers to [iterated composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) (inverse for $-1$). While this is not ambiguous for trig functions as there is an established convention of positive superscripts referring to powers and using $-1$ for the inverse, this is not the case more generally, where $f^n$ could refer to a power of $f$ or an iterated function. For that reason, it is clearer to write $f^\prime(x)^2$ to indicate the square of the derivative of $f$.

Comment: +1. I suspect that the common trig notations like $\sin^2 x$ for $(\sin x)^2$ arose when someone got tired of writing so many brackets.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: good point. Apart from non-ambiguity simplicity is also desired in a notation. No one really wants to write unnecessary parentheses. When I write $\sin x^2$ I mean $\sin (x^2)$ and not $(\sin x) ^2$. Unfortunately function other than trig don't seem to have similar convention.